# Using setenv() in C

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, environment-variables

I am trying to understand how setenv() works. The documentation is

```
setenv (const char *name, const char *value, int overwrite)
```

I want to be able to edit the environment variable array. For example I want to set

```
envp[1] = "Hello World"
```

I am confused by the setenv function though and not sure how to implement in the function. Would the overwrite be the index of the environment array. Would this affect the printing of all the environments like this?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(int argc, char *argv[], char * envp[])
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; envp[i] != NULL; i++)
    {    
        printf("\n%s", envp[i]);
    }
}
```

So instead of what normally would be at envp[1] it is changed to "Hello World". I'm also not sure if overwrite set at 1 means envp[1].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want to modify the environment variable array? **envp** is just a copy of environment variables when the program starts.

First , "Hello World" is not a valid environment variable. An environment variable is just like any other variable that has an identifier(name) and a value. It is okay to have an environment variable STR=HelloWorld.

If you just want to set the above environment variable, you just call `setenv("STR", "HelloWorld", 1)`. The overwrite flag 1 ensures that the previous value of STR is overwritten by this function. If the overwrite flag is 0, setenv does not change the value of the environment variable if it's already set.

> Would this affect the printing of all the environments like this?

It does not change the value when I tested it with gcc. The reason is that `getenv()` and `setenv()` function are used in pairs to access environment variables. The c string array **envp** is just the environment variable array when the program starts. Also, **envp** is usually not passing around from main function, which means other functions are not aware of **envp**.

Comment: “Hello World” is a valid name for an environment variable. The documentation for it on macOS 10.14.6 does not mention any restriction except that it should not be empty or contain `=`. And `setenv("Hello World", "foo")` returns 0, after which `getenv("Hello World")` returns a pointer to a string containing “foo”.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Yes -- but I'm finding (on Ubuntu 18.04) that after `setenv("hello world", "foo bar")` and invoking another program, that program doesn't see that variable in its environment. I'm in the midst of trying to figure out what's going on.

Comment: @KeithThompson Note that shells (e.g., bash, ksh, zsh) can only use env vars whose name are valid var names. So while you can define an env var named "hello world" you won't be able to use it in most shells. Also, when you say "invoking another program" if you mean anything other than the program which called `setenv()` starting another program then, yes, that other program won't see the var.

Comment: @KurtisRader: Yes, I meant the program that called `setenv()` starting another program. Further experiments indicate that on my system (Ubuntu 18.04), `/bin/sh` (a symlink to `/bin/dash`) removes environment variables with spaces in their names on startup. Other shells (`bash`, `tcsh`) don't do this. If I invoke a program using `system()`, it goes through `/bin/sh`, and the `Hello World` environment variable is cleared. If I use `execv` to invoke something else directly, it isn't (`env | grep hello` shows `hello world=foo`in the example I used).

Comment: @EricPostpischil: See the above comment.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Just for curiosity, does `/bin/dash` remove environment variables with spaces or merely not display and expand them? For example, suppose you set `Hello World` to `foo`, then invoke `/bin/dash` via `system()`, then, inside `/bin/dash`, execute a program that prints all its environment variables, does that program show `Hello World`?

Comment: @EricPostpischil: `system()` invokes the command via `/bin/sh`, which on my system is `/bin/dash`. My test program uses `execl` to invoke the program directly. After I do `setenv("hello world", "foo", 1);`, if I then call `execl` to invoke `perl`, `bash`, `tcsh`, `ksh`, `fish`, or `env`, I see `hello world` set to `foo`. `dash` and `busybox sh` are the only commands I've found that filters it out. Looking at the [dash sources](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/dash/dash.git), I see where it does this (in `var.c`). It only allows names that are identifiers. busybox changed this in 2017.